How to keep the iformfile, when an Exception occurs inside the Action method?
I wrote a program with asp.net core.
In this program, the user enters the required information about an article (such as the image and description text, etc.) and then presses the "upload article" button. The image of the article is uploaded and other information is also stored in the database. Normally everything works fine.
But
The problem happens when an exception occurs (or an exception is thrown) and I display the view again. When the view is displayed again, the value of "mainImage" corresponding to the image of the article becomes null.
**How can I prevent it from becoming null or restore its value?
**
my view:
@model DataLayer.Article
@{
    var errorMessage = "";
    var hasError = false;
    if (TempData["ExceptionMessage"] != null)
    {
        hasError = true;
        errorMessage = @TempData["ExceptionMessage"].ToString();
        <div class="alert alert-danger fill">
            <i class="icon-check"></i>
            <strong>خطا!</strong>
            @errorMessage
        </div>
    }

}
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="row">

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="CreateArticleForm" >
        <fieldset>
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.ArticleId)
           
            <div class="panel panel-success box shadow">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <a id="tab1lbl"> اطلاعات کلی</a>
                        <div class="vl"></div>
                        <a id="tab2lbl">متن توضیحات</a>
                       


                    </div><!-- /.panel-title -->

                </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->
                <div class="wizard-step" id="tab1">
                    <!-- اطلاعات کلی-->
                    <div class="form-group ">
                      
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span>
                                <i class="far fa-circle-question"></i>
                                                    
                                <label  asp-for="IsStaticPost" class="control-label"></label>
                           </span>

                            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="IsStaticPost" style="margin-right: 10px;" />
                     
                           

                        </div><!-- /.input-group -->
                        <span asp-validation-for="IsStaticPost" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                    <div class="form-group  relative">

                        <input type="file" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg" name="mainImage" >
                        <label asp-for="ImageName" class="control-label"></label>
                        <div class="input-group round">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="icon-picture"></i>
                            </span>


                            <input type="text" asp-for="ImageName" class="form-control file-input"
                                   placeholder="برای انتخاب کلیک کنید" >

                        </div><!-- /.input-group -->
                        <span asp-validation-for="ImageName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ImageAlt" class="control-label"></label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <img src="~/Images/ImageAlt.svg" />
                            </span>

                            <input asp-for="ImageAlt" class="form-control" />

                        </div><!-- /.input-group -->
                        <span asp-validation-for="ImageAlt" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ImageTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <img src="~/Images/ImageTitle.svg" />
                            </span>

                            <input asp-for="ImageTitle" class="form-control" />

                        </div><!-- /.input-group -->
                        <span asp-validation-for="ImageTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ShortDescription" class="control-label"></label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <img src="~/Images/tag32.png" />
                            </span>

                            <input asp-for="ShortDescription" class="form-control" />

                        </div><!-- /.input-group -->
                        <span asp-validation-for="ShortDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="BrowserTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fas fa-earth-asia"></i>
                            </span>

                            <input asp-for="BrowserTitle" class="form-control" />

                        </div><!-- /.input-group -->
                        <span asp-validation-for="BrowserTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <img src="~/Images/tag32.png" />
                            </span>

                            <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />

                        </div><!-- /.input-group -->
                        <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->


                  

                  
                </div><!-- /.wizard-step -->
                <div class="wizard-step" id="tab2">
                    <!-- متن توضیحات-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Text" class="control-label"></label>
                        <div class="input-group">

                            <textarea asp-for="Text"></textarea>

                        </div><!-- /.input-group -->
                        <span asp-validation-for="Text" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">کلمات کلیدی</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <img src="~/Images/tag32.png" />
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="لطفا کلمات کلیدی را با ,  از هم جداکنید" class="form-control"  value="@ViewBag.Tags"/>


                        </div><!-- /.input-group -->

                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                </div>

                <div class="wizard-nav">

                    <button type="button" id="wizard-prev" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <i class="fas fa-angles-right"></i>
                        قبلی
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" id="wizard-next" class="btn btn-danger">
                        <i class="fas fa-angles-left"></i>
                        بعدی
                    </button>


                  @*   upload article button  *@
                    <button type="submit" id="wizard-submit" class="btn btn-success">
                        <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
                        بارگذاری مقاله   
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>






@section Scripts {


    <script src="~/assets/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/assets/plugins/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/assets/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }


    <script>
       
        $(function () {
            $('#Text').ckeditor();
        });




    </script>
  



}






my action method:
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ImageTitle,ImageAlt,ShortKey,ArticleId,ImageName,BrowserTitle,ShortDescription,Title,Text,CreateOrUpdateDate,FauthorId,IsPublished,IsStaticPost")] Article article,
       IFormFile mainImage, string? tags)
  {
      string farsiError;
      string srcImg;
      string[] tagArray;
      string imageName;
      Guid articleId;
      AdminUser author;
      bool isExistsStaticPost;
      try
      {
          ModelState.Remove("Fauthor");
          ModelState.Remove("ShortKey");
        //  if (!ModelState.IsValid && mainImage==null && ModelState.Keys.)
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
              if ((mainImage != null) && (mainImage.Length > _maxImageSize))
              {
                  ModelState.AddModelError("ImageName", "حجم تصویر اصلی بیشتر از 100 کیلوبایت نمی تواند باشد.");
                  ViewBag.Tags = tags;
                  return View();
              }
              isExistsStaticPost = _context.Articles.Any(a => a.IsStaticPost);
              if (isExistsStaticPost && article.IsStaticPost)
              {
                  farsiError = "یک مطلب قبلا بصورت پست ثابت تعریف شده است. ابتدا آن را از حالت پست ثابت خارج کنید.";
                  throw new Exception(farsiError);
              }

              else
              {
                  article.ShortKey = GenerateShortKey();
                  author = _context.AdminUsers.Where(u => u.Username == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                  article.Fauthor = author;
                  article.FauthorId = author.Id;
                  articleId = article.ArticleId;
                  imageName = "No-Image.jpg";

                  if (mainImage != null && CheckContentImage.IsImage(mainImage))
                  {


                      imageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(mainImage.FileName);
                      srcImg = _imgFolder + imageName;
                      article.ImageName = imageName;

                      if (mainImage.Length > 0)
                      {

                          using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(srcImg, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                          {
                              mainImage.CopyTo(fileStream);
                          }
                      }


                      ImageResizer resizer = new ImageResizer();
                      resizer.Resize(srcImg, _thumbFolder + imageName);
                  }


                  article.CreateOrUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;

                  _context.Articles.Add(article);





                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tags))
                  {
                      tagArray = tags.Split(',');
                      foreach (string tag in tagArray)
                      {
                          _context.ArticleTags.Add(new DataLayer.ArticleTag()
                          {
                              FarticleId = articleId,
                              TagText = tag.Trim()
                          });
                      }
                  }



                  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


                  return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
              }
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          farsiError = ex.GetFarsiMessage(); //پیغام مناسب فارسی برای تکرای بودن 
          TempData["ExceptionMessage"] = farsiError;
         
          ViewBag.Tags = tags;

      }

      return View();


  }


Based on your scenario and description, in order to handle file re-upload in ASP.NET Core when an exception occurs, store the uploaded file temporarily in memory or a temporary location and use TempData to preserve the file's metadata and content. Modify the action method to save file data and other form inputs in TempData during an exception, and update the view to check TempData for the file and re-display it along with other preserved form data. This ensures that users do not lose their uploaded file or entered information if an error occurs and the form needs to be re-rendered.

"update the view to check TempData for the file and re-display it along with other preserved form data"   how to update inputfile value??


You can't because returned view is a completely new page and you can't set value for file inputs.
You can submit the form with ajax and handle the response from server with javascript, redirect or display alert message.
